# Need examples for FtpGetFile, not working

Tags: c++, windows, ftp, download, wininet

This is my current code but it doesn't do anything. Also i wanted it to open do.bat after downloading is complete

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <wininet.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
            HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL,INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,NULL,NULL,0); // Initialization for WinInet Functions
HINTERNET hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet,"server",INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,"user","pass", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP,INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE,0);  // Starts a session in this case an FTP session
FtpGetFile(hInternet,"do.bat","C:\\do.bat",FALSE,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII,0);






    InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession); // Close hFtpSession
InternetCloseHandle(hInternet); // Close hInternet    

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

WOW, no thanks again, Just a noobie mistake. I needed to replace

**FtpGetFile(hInternet,"do.bat","C:\do.bat",FALSE,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII,0);**

with

**FtpGetFile(hFtpSession,"do.bat","C:\do.bat",FALSE,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII,0);**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <wininet.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
            HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL,INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,NULL,NULL,0); // Initialization for WinInet Functions
   HINTERNET hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet,"ftp.drivehq.com",INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,"merzu","8067-MPSE", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP,INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE,0);  // Starts a session in this case an FTP session
FtpGetFile(hFtpSession,"do.bat","do.bat",TRUE,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII,0);






     InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession); // Close hFtpSession
   InternetCloseHandle(hInternet); // Close hInternet    

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```